# Core Data: Can I add a relationship to the parent entity?

Tags: core-data, attributes, entity-relationship, parent, nsmanagedobject

I made the `Photo` entity, which has a `Data` attribute to store the image data. `Photo` is the parent of the `Thumbnail` entity. I also added a one-to-one relationship between `Photo` and `Thumbnail` so that a `Photo` can have a `Thumbnail`.

This seems to work but is sort of confusing.

Do you think it's better design to make another entity called `Image` that has the image data attribute and make `Photo` & `Thumbnail` children of `Image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think it's better design to
>   make another entity called Image that
>   has the image data attribute and make
>   Photo & Thumbnail children of Image?

You shouldn't look at entity inheritance as a means of making a tidy design but instead it should be used such that multiple entities can inhabit the same relationship.

Suppose you had a `Person` entity that had image data but the images where of different sizes or types but you needed all the image entities to be in the same relationship. You would set things up like so:

```
Person{
    images<-->>Image.person
}

Image{
    person<<-->Person.images
}

GIF:Image{
    //... GIF related attributes
}

JPG:Image{
    //... JPG related attributes
}
```

Because the `GIF` and `JPG` entities inherit from `Image` you can put both in the `Person.images` relationship.

In your case, there appears to be no particular reason, other than analogy to Classes, to make the `Photo` and `Thumbnail` inherit from a common super entity.

Also, if you are using an SQLite store, all the subentities of a parent entity end up in the same table. For very large data sets, this can create performance problems. So, that is another reason not to use entity inheritance just for neatness.

Comment: Thanks! I'm considering your argument for entity inheritance for relationships. So, are you saying I should remove the Resources entity in my question on [When to store images as binary data in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827105/when-to-store-images-as-binary-data-in-core-data)?

Comment: There are times though, that I'd like to share the same methods between the two subclasses. What's an alternative to subclassing for achieving this? For example, I give Photo & User a super class called Resource that has an id (which matches the id on the server). What if I want to put common networking code in Resource that Photo & User can share (like fetching a resource from the server)?

Comment: Also, it may give the Resource table twice as many rows in SQLite, but won't these rows be short (3 columns: pk, id, type), and won't it take out the id column from the User & Photo tables? So, it may be less efficient, but what about the niceties of sharing the code of the superclass with the subclasses?

Comment: Managed object subclasses and entities don't have to have the same inheritance. You could have both the Photo & User classes inherit from a common superclass even if the entities in the data model don't share inheritance.